# Unable remove python-mysql.connector in Ubuntu Server 16.04

Tags: 16.04, server, python, mysql

I installed python-mysql.connector and python3-mysql.connector on my server. and set python 3.5 as my default python. 
Now I want to remove python-mysql.connector but get the following error:

```
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
```

I searched it and found in python3 `ConfigParser` changed to `configparser` and I think this is the reason that prevent remove the package.
I use [this](https://www.howtoinstall.co/en/ubuntu/trusty/python-mysql.connector?action=remove) to remove python3-mysql.connector and it was ok but I don't know how to remove pyhton-mysql.connector

Any idea would help me.
Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Revert back to Python 2.x as default, then remove *python-mysql.connector*. Not sure if it is a good idea to *change* the default Python version as other scripts may rely on that Python 2.x is default and might crash.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. As I said the problem was python 3.5 that was set as default.
So as [@Thomas](https://askubuntu.com/users/490838/thomas) suggested to reverting back to python 2.x I did this and problem solved:

remove symbolic link to python 3.5

```
sudo rm /usr/bin/python
```

set python 2.7 as default

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/python
```

testing

```
python --version
```

hope help to others